# Multiple column inputs for plotting multiple y axis from one csv in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a r shiny page in my thesis work. I want to know that from one comma separated file ,how can i give multiple columns as input for multiple y axis in R shiny. I'm trying with checkbox group input. If is there any other way please let me know .
Please help me , I'm stuck at this point. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. However if I have understood correctly you want a user to choose different columns of a data set.

The way to do this is to use a `uiOutput` in the ui and a `selectizeInput` in the server.

I would advise that you read up on these on the shiny website.

The code below is not my own however I have forgotten where I have taken it from as it is a file on my computer so I apologise for the lack of reference. It is an example which lets the user choose which columns of a data set are shown in a data table.

Im guessing that in your case you would use this method to subset and then render your plots.

```
#DRAG AND DROP

library(shiny)  
library(DT)

dat <- mtcars

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("ui_view_vars")
),
mainPanel(
  tabPanel("View", DT::dataTableOutput("dataviewer"))
)
   )
 ))

 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$ui_view_vars <- renderUI({
vars <- colnames(dat)


selectizeInput("view_vars", "Select variables to show:", choices  = vars,
               selected = vars, multiple = TRUE,
               options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
   })

   output$dataviewer <- DT::renderDataTable({
if (is.null(input$view_vars)) return()
DT::datatable(dat[,input$view_vars])
   })
 })

 # Run the application  
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```